# Multiple KMLs and 414 Error: Request-URI Too Large

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, maps, kml

I've got plenty of KML files - one for each of the existing countries. I need to render them dynamically on Google Map based on user's input. If I there are only a few countries as result of searching, everything works perfectly - the map displays all the countries. The problem occurs when there are more than about 15 countries do highlight. I get 414 errors for almost all KML requests.

As far as I know, Google Map is divided on tiles and for each of the tiles, one KML request is proceeded. If there's too many KML files that need generated for a tile, then URL for such a request is too long (414 error).

Do you have any idea how can I overcome this problem?

Here is an example of such a request:

```
http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=pl&lyrs=kml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3izLNIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq1ixq5IeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iz7ZIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq1iy61IeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq2CfZHwyIkHtAg|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iw6xIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq2aCOyKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq1ix7BIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq2aCAyLhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq1iy7lIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iya1IeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iPRGKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3ixrdIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq1ix7xIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iMxGKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq1iNwGKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iybBIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iPBGKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3ixrNIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iw7NIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3ixrBIeOTEA1oE|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq1iNxGKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq3iNTGKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq2aCMyLhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3%2Ckml%3AcuwPC5SCy4YxYqf-KUu31-kH0-baWhlLmIlHaxq2aANyKhEdOPKBF|kv%3A3|api%3A3&x=1&y=1&z=1&w=256&h=256&source=maps_api&token=104074
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have to have them in separate kml files can you just output your xml with multiple folders and within each folder is each area just an idea let me know if its rubbish